# Why all token is valid using jwt auth in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

When I login multiple time and then JWT Auth generate multiple token and all token is valid why. I need only one token valid.

Comment: Please show your codes

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in mechanism to it, but you can do it by storing all the created token in database and check manually, also you can use `JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());` to invalidate any token. Check some thread in github to get better idea on it.

1. [Ability to expire all user tokens](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/97)
2. [Max tokens per user](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/258)
3. [Blacklist Based on User ID](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/300)